# Unable to add a breakpoint in IntelliJ 15

Tags: java, scala, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm debugging a failing test and am unable to add a breakpoint to a particular line, is anyone able to help at all?

I've searched on SO and come across the post that relates to the python plugin - which i don't have installed and also tried invalidating caches and restarting which didn't help.

What is interesting is that the lines I cannot add a breakpoint to both access the same variable and so I'm wondering if perhaps that has something to do with it.  I'm fairly new to scala so there could be something obvious that I'm missing, also extracted out the code to a separate function hopping I could 'trick' intellij but no joy.

```
private var mutableList = mutable.ListBuffer[((A, B, C), D)]
```

This line is causing problmes:

```
for (item <- items) {
if (x) { 
if (y) { //stuff } 
mutableList += (AA,BB, Function to generate CC) -> DD //Cannot place break point
}
```

also after that if block we have another instance where I can't place one:

```
for (item <- items)
if (x) //above code block

if (mutableList .contains((AA, BB, Function to generate CC) -> DD)) {
            another var += AA -> DD
          }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which version of scala are you compiling against?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Hi there, I'm using 2.10.4

Comment: We are seeing a bug with IntelliJ 15 and running scala tests on 2.10. It attempts to run them as 2.11 for some reason, and the breakpoints aren't hit. I'm trying to lookup the issue in the JetBrains issue tracker.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Thank you so much~! I thought i was going mad for a moment :)  We were using 2.11 but then downgraded for dependency reasons.  Thank you for the information, any idea when the bug may be resolved?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I'm trying to look for it and contact someone at JetBrains. When you upgrade to 2.11, can you debug properly?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I can test and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know why you cant place breakpoints at those lines, but you can place the breakpoint one line above and then once it hits it use `F8` instead of `F9` to go to the next line.

Edit : also make shure you run the program in debug mode `shift` + `F9`